# after saving delphi form, it loses accented characters

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I got some forms in Delphi 7 which I open in my IDE. Certain accented characters are not displayed correctly in the form and when I change a form containing such a character , the accent is lost.

E.g. something encoded as #337 a in dfm becomes u in the saved dfm

Can you tell what may be wrong?

update:
Problem for fixed after I changed in Control Panel, Region and Language, Tab Formats.
I changed the format from English to the language that has accented character.

Comment: You really need Unicode Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi 7 does not support Unicode, only ASCII. That's why the "extra" characters are not displayed.

The controls are capable of showing unicode (because Windows does). But the dfm files are still ASCII, and you have no guarantees about characters above 127. (And the VCL does not support them either).

You can switch to 2010 or 2011 (XE) for Unicode support.

Comment: To be honest I doubt this is entirely true. We are using Delphi 2006, which is not Unicode, and accents as in ´ do not get lost. For example, the word "Previsión" will be stored in the DFM as "Previsi'#243'n". As far as I can remember this was not an issue in Delphi 7, but I can not test it.

Comment: You might get lucky with characters that have equivalents within the 128-255 range. But a #337 won't work.

Comment: Well, somehow it got fixed...I changed a local setting and a lot of things... So it can be fixed.

Comment: It uses what Microsoft calls ANSI, i.e. the locale dependent charset.

Comment: Use WideString instead of String! You don`t need to convert it because WideString=String. I am using WideString because I live in Latvia and everything works fine. :))

Answer (score 2):

In a non-unicode delphi version (delphi 7 for instance), if your current codepage supports a character, then Delphi will store your accent character into the DFM. If you reload on a system that is set to a different codepage, you won't see that character.

In a unicode Delphi (2009 or later) you will be able to store any codepoint you want into the DFMs.

Comment: @Warren_P : is this codepage configured in Windows? Or it is a configuration inside Delphi?

Comment: The codepage is a regional setting in windows, as "Language for Non-Unicode programs".  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_select_language_version.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score -4):

AFAIR, all dfm content is encoded as UTF-8, in the dfm files produced by Delphi 7.

So you could be able to use whatever character you need.

But you need to set the proper Font CharSet property value for the component.

Comment: All dfm content is NOT in UTF-8, it's in ANSI in Delphi 7.